# How i can use knp_paginator in my own service?

Tags: symfony

I want use knp_paginator in my own service but I don't know how do this.

I try:

```
services:
  example:
    class: Common\ToolsBundle\Utils\Example
    arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @knp_paginator ]
```

but I received an error:

> ServiceNotFoundException in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 58:
>   The service "example" has a dependency on a non-existent service "knp_paginator".

Thank you for any help

Comment: Are you sure you include KnpPaginator bundle in AppKernel?

Comment: you can try  `arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@knp_paginator "]`

Comment: Omg I forgot about this... Thank you.

Comment: Look here for answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45876792/using-knp-paginator-within-my-own-service/45878196?noredirect=1#comment78715128_45878196