# Using knp_paginator within my own service

Tags: php, symfony, knppaginatorbundle

I am trying to use the knp_paginator within my own service but i get this error

> ServiceNotFoundException in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 58: The service "paginatorservice" has a dependency on a non-existent service "knp_paginator ".

This is my service :

```
namespace CommonBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class PaginatorService
{

  public function paginate($query, $pageLimit, $pageNumber)
  {

    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $query,
        $request->query->getInt('page', $pageNumber),
        $pageLimit 
    );

    return $pagination;
  }

}
```

my service.yml:

```
paginatorservice:
    class: CommonBundle\Service\PaginatorService
    arguments: 
        entityManager: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@knp_paginator "]
```

The paginator works fine in my controller but i want to make it a service so i can reuse the code.

Comment: You have an extra space in your `service.yml`, in `"@knp_paginator "`, remove the space between the `r` and the `"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

I the service.yml I have to pass 3 arguments, 'entitymanager', 'knp_paginator' and 'request_stack' since request will be used in the service.

```
paginatorservice:
    class: CommonBundle\Service\PaginatorService
    arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@knp_paginator","@request_stack"]
```

My service class now looks like this.

```
namespace CommonBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class PaginatorService
{

    private $em;
    private $paginator;
    protected $requestStack;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, $paginator,RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->paginator = $paginator;
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public function paginate($query, $pageLimit, $pageNumber)
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

        $pagination = $this->paginator->paginate(
            $query,
            $request->query->getInt('page', $pageNumber),
            $pageLimit 
        );

        return $pagination;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should inject them on the __construct of your service:

```
$private $em;
$private $paginator;
public function __contruct($em, $paginator){
   $this->em = $em;
   $this->$paginator = $paginator;
}
```

And change:

```
paginatorservice:
    class: CommonBundle\Service\PaginatorService
    arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@knp_paginator"]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I still get the same error, maybe i am forgetting a use statement or something?

Comment: remember the whitespace I commented in the question!

Comment: Did you try removing cache?